# Leaflet options for pop ups

Tags: leaflet, popup

In leaflet what are the tools that are best for pop ups or other options such as enhanced click through and animation?

I would like to have multiple sets of data displayed as pop ups and then I would also like to have an option of a side bar to display more information once I click on a button with the pop up? I have tried using Jquery to do this but unsuccessful. Any ideas on how to achieve this?